# Always show zoom controls on a MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there a way to always show the zoom controls on a MapView? I have added the zoom controls using

```
map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

but the zoom controls fade in and out. I want them to always be visible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved this by putting my own ZoomControls in my layout xml:

```
<ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomcontrols"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then setting up onClickListeners for then to handle the zoom:

```
    zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrols);
    zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomIn();
        }
    });
    zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomOut();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what about "mapController" ?

Answer (score 15):

Intrications' solution does work, but you lose the built in functionality where the button disables when you have zoomed in or out all the way. You can retain this functionality by using the following instead:

```
localMapView.getZoomButtonsController().setAutoDismissed(false);
```

However, this does not let you place the controls wherer you want in the panel, and although it does not go away, it does not show up the first time until the user touches the screen once. I tried calling `setVisible(true)` on the controller, but that does not seem to work for some reason.