# How to layout zoom Control with setBuiltInZoomControls(true)?

Tags: android, android-mapview

would like to add a zoom control to the map. I also want to layout the position of the zoom Control instead of the default middle bottom position. I can do this by getZoomControl but it is deprecated.

Could anyone tell me how to do this with `setBuildtInZoomControls`?

Answer (score 9):

This is how I got mine working finally (by embedding a ZoomControl in XML layout).

```
mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrols);
zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getController().zoomIn();
        }
});
zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapView.getController().zoomOut();
        }
});
```

See: [Always show zoom controls on a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920741/always-show-zoom-controls-on-a-mapview)

Answer (score 1):

```
mapView.getZoomButtonsController()
```

Although this is undocumented (at least in the javadoc available here: [com.google.android.maps](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html)) I am quite sure this is the replacement for the deprecated `getZoomControls`

Edit: just found out that it *is* documented, just not in the google api docs but rather here: [ZoomButtonsController on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.html)

You could then call `getContainer ()` or `getZoomControls ()` (depending on what you want to do) to get access to the zoom controls view.

And then do something like

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoomParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
zoomParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
mapView.getZoomButtonsController().getZoomControls().setLayoutParams(zoomParams);
```

although I have to admit that I am not sure what layout the maps view uses, could be LinearLayout as well.

Comment: The 'RelativeLayout.LayoutParams' throws a class cast exception.  FrameLayout.LayoutParams is what is required, though I'm stumped on how to get this to work

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_zoom);
View mapController = mapView.getZoomButtonsController().getZoomControls();
zoomLayout.addView(mapController, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the only way to do this is to either use the [MapView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html)'s deprecated [getZoomControls()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getZoomControls%28%29) or to DIY it. The [MapController](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html) has the methods necessary (e.g. [zoomIn()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#zoomIn%28%29) and [zoomOut()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#zoomOut%28%29)).

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
setContentView(relativeLayout);

final MapView mapView = new MapView(this, DEBUG_MAP_API_KEY);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mapViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
relativeLayout.addView(mapView, mapViewLayoutParams);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoomControlsLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
zoomControlsLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
zoomControlsLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

relativeLayout.addView(mapView.getZoomControls(), zoomControlsLayoutParams);

mapView.setClickable(true);
mapView.setEnabled(true);
```

I think this should work ... Hope this is useful :)

Comment: This also uses the deprecated getZoomControls functions of the mapview.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321984/george) on [Placing Zoom Controls in a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263507/placing-zoom-controls-in-a-mapview) allows to layout the built in zoom controls by using gravity attributes. This attribute positions the element into its container which seems that is positioned on the bottom of the screen so its not possible to position the zoom controls on the top of the screen by layouting the zoom controls.

In conclusion you can layout the built in zoom controls by doing:

```
((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mapView.getZoomButtonsController().getZoomControls().getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Remember that the zoom controls are contained into a `FrameLayout` therefore any try to use rules like `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` or `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP` will lead you only to pain and sorrow.