# How to position MapView's zoom controls to a different location on the screen?

Tags: android, android-mapview

android.view.View.getZoomControls() is deprecated, and the MapView reference says to use the out-of-the-box setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean) instead.  However, I want to not only *show* the zoom controls, but be able to *move* it to a different location on the screen, i.e. lower-right. How can I get a reference to the built-in zoom controls - without using the deprecated method above - to control its location?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the solution that i posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768097/how-to-layout-zoom-control-with-setbuiltinzoomcontrolstrue/13843591#13843591

Answer (score 0):

I dug around and found:

```
    ZoomControls controls = (ZoomControls) mapView.getZoomButtonsController().getZoomControls();
```

My Eclipse does not give a warning about anything above being deprecated.  However, when I search the MapView reference for getZoomButtonsController, I do not find such a method!  So, I guess, it's an undocumented, but non-deprecated method in the API.