# How to make Google map zoom controls will appear automatically?

Tags: android

I have developed a google map app and the zoom controls will not appear automatically
and will disappear after they are used.

So I want to see the zoom controls (_ , +) to appear with the map permanently.

Thanx in adv

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920741/always-show-zoom-controls-on-a-mapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Always show zoom controls on a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920741/always-show-zoom-controls-on-a-mapview)