# Always show zoom controls in WebView

Tags: java, android, controls, cordova, zooming

Is there any way to always show zoom controls in webview?
I found this: [Always show zoom controls on a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920741/always-show-zoom-controls-on-a-mapview)
but that's for the mapview.
I want them to always be visible.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();
    ws.setSupportZoom(true);
    ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setDisplayZoomControls() is only available from API 11 (Android 3). So you can't even consider using it until the vast majority of Android devices are 3 or above - which will not be for some years :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as I never tried, but I checked the reference in developer.android.com

```
ws.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
```

Also check this out:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130931/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/02/webview-with-zoomcontrols-in-android.html

good tutorial. (Debunks my theory)

Comment: Not working! It says that ws doesn't have function setDisplayZoomControls.

Comment: .setDisplayZoomControls(Boolean enabled) is a standard method for WebSettings so that doesn't make much sense. Try replacing it instead of .setBuiltInZoomControls.

Comment: look at the link i edited into the answer. That should get it working

Comment: I was on that link earlier. A lot of errors. And replacing is not working.

Comment: try this:
final View zoom = super.appView.getZoomControls();
zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: if you have to add a framelayout or relativelayout then add the zoom into the layout (framelayouts and relativelayouts allow views to overlay each other)

Comment: With this final View zoom = super.appView.getZoomControls(); zoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); the app won't start.

Comment: what does the ddms say? Plus super.appView might not be correct, I am just guessing that is your webview based off the code you gave

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for my. Only when I start draging the webview content the controls show up the first time. So what I did as a "quick fix" is in onStart() of my Fragment that holds the Dialog with the webview I call:

```
webview.invokeZoomPicker();
```

Example:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        DialogFragment dialog = this;
       //...stuff
        if(dialog.getDialog()!= null && dialog.getDialog().getWindow()!=null){
            //...more stuff
            View v = dialog.getView();
            if(v!=null){
                //invoke controls on start once, they stay active a few seconds:
                WebView webview =v.findViewById(R.id.frag_dlg_WebView);
                webview.invokeZoomPicker();
            }
        }
    }
```

The controls light up only for a few seconds until they disappear again, by then the user in my case should have dragged the webview already.