# How to show builtin Zoom Controlls in webview in Android

Tags: android, webview, android-listview, android-webview, zooming

may be duplicate to this [Always show zoom controls in WebView[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866710/always-show-zoom-controls-in-webview) but I just want to display the zoom controls not necessary always.

Basically i have a list View and i fill this with the multiple webview in getVIew Method.

Here is the code

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_reader_list_style, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.webView = (WebView) vi.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            WebSettings webSettings = holder.webView.getSettings();
            holder.webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            holder.webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            holder.webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);

            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            holder.webView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Webview", "Clicked");

                }
            });

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.webView
                .loadDataWithBaseURL(
                        null,
                        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img style=\"border-style:dotted;border-width:5px;border-color:black;\" src= "
                                + URLs.get(position)
                                + " alt=\"page Not Found\"></body></html>",
                        "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        return vi;

    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    WebView webView;

}
```

and here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

listview is filled with webviews nicely but problem is that i want the Zoom button controls.

- Please have a look on my XML and Java Code. What i m doing wrong?

I have tried the

```
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

but still not working

Comment: Your requirement is not clear

Comment: i want the built-in zoom controls (Buttons) in my webview in short

Comment: your code webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); will give this

Comment: not appearing thats why i posted the question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make  **android:clickable="false"** to  **android:clickable="true"**. In your webView XML. You can remove focusable or make them true also

Comment: it worked some how.. i think my list view's touch event conflicts with my web view's touch event

Comment: May be..But if it conflict then you need to handle it

Comment: do you have WebView inside listview or vice versa? If you do not have then i think both touch event will not conflict

Comment: is it possible to always show the zoom Controls over the webview ?

Comment: Hi Coder  i have used but still does not working please see below site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497943/zoom-in-out-in-webview-android

Answer (score 1):

in oncreate() method

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and always search before asking.it reduces redundancy & saves your time.

once check this mate.

[zoom controls for webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049343/how-to-control-zoom-in-webview)

Comment: I have tried this. but not appearing and i m searching regarding this since previous 5 hours.