# webview wont open a url zoomed out

Tags: android

I am trying the following code but it does not open the page in the desired way I want. It opens the URL in a mobile type page even with this code. I want the page to open completely zoomed out. I mean I want to see the full page instead of scrolling it. here's the code

```
 browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browserview);
            browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

appreciating help. thanks

Comment: I tried like browser.loadurl(http://www.mybringback.com

Comment: I think this Might Help you to get your Answer !!!


[Zoom Controlls][1] and [Control Zoom in webView][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438369/how-to-show-builtin-zoom-controlls-in-webview-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049343/how-to-control-zoom-in-webview

Comment: I don't want any zoom controls. Just the page to be zoomed out so I can fully see it. That stuff is too complicated for me, I am a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these following lines it will works.

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Comment: Hey shahinoor, I am sorry but your code worked for me. Can you explain it to me a little bit as I am a beginner.